# Clang-Format. How to make function parameters to be on their own line if line is too long?

Tags: clang-format

Now I have that behaviour:

```
void methodName(int arg1,
                int arg2,
                int arg3) { 
   ...
}
```

I want:

```
void methodName(
   int arg1,
   int arg2,
   int arg3
) { 
   ...
}
```

zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz